# PostgreSQL how to merge jsonb keys and count values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, facet

I have a table that looks somthing like the following:

| id | name | category | specs (jsonb) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | product1 | phones | { "brand": "brand1", "color": "red", "size": 5, "memory": "8GB"} |
| 2 | product2 | phones | { "brand": "brand1", "color": "white", "size": 7, "memory": "8GB"} |
| 3 | product3 | laptops | { "brand": "brand20", "storage": "SSD", "os": "os1" , "memory": "32GB"} |

My desired output given a specific category

```
{
    "brand": {
       "brand1": 1,
       "brand2": 1
    },
    "color": {
       "red": 1,
       "white": 5,
    },
    "memory": {
        "8gb": 2,
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt with us and explain the reason why it didn't work?

Comment: What is the reason to not include `size` in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blow out the specs column with `jsonb_each_text()`, calculate the counts, and then reassemble with `jsonb_object_agg()` (the first two CTEs could be combined into one, but I left them verbose for illustration):

```
with blowout as (
  select s.category, j.key, j.value
    from somthing s
         cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(s.specs) as j(key, value)
), counts as (
  select category, key, value, count(1) as cnt
    from blowout
   group by category, key, value
), agg_specs as (
  select category, key, jsonb_object_agg(value, cnt) as counts
    from counts
   group by category, key
)
select category, jsonb_object_agg(key, counts) as output
  from agg_specs
 group by category
;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b17e6c88fb61958c05a1d25f927db734)*

Comment: "*given a specific category*" sounds like OP rather wants a `where s.category = 'phones'` than carrying it through to an output column. But +1 nonetheless!